# How to get queryset value outside of loop in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this below scenario as an example

Current scenario

```
{% for city in cities %}
    <div id="{{city.country}}">
        <p>Choose a city</p>
        <li>{{ city.name }}</li>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

What I want

```
<div id="{{city.country}}">
    <p>Choose a city</p>    
       {% for city in cities %}
           <li>{{ city.name }}</li>
       {% endfor %}    
</div>
```

How can I achieve that? 
Thanks

Comment: looks like you need a list of countries along with the cities inside and then you probably can. Rework your data structure in your view to do something like `[{"countryname": [{"name": etc...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @erework said I restructured the data in my view. If you have any better ways, feel free to edit. Below is how I did it:

```
#views.py
from django.conf import settings
cities = []
for country in settings.COUNTRIES:
    cities.append([country, City.objects.filter(country=country)])


#cities.html
{% for country, city in cities %}
    <div id="{{country}}">
        <p>Choose a city</p>
        <li>{{ city.name }}</li>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I wanted my cities list to be sorted by country hence I put the data into a list. Also I only had less than 10 countries so I had a list of them in settings file.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using the built in [{% regroup %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) template tag is more elegant.

It would be something along these lines (not tested):

```
{% regroup cities by country as country_list %}

{% for country in country_list %}
    <div id="{{country.grouper}}">
        <p>Choose a city</p>    
        {% for city in country.list %}
            <li>{{ city.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}    
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Interestingly, the example in official Django docs also uses cities and countries. Check it out (linked above).